# python int object not iterable error while trying to run the below code

Tags: python

```
import sys
import itertools
arr = [[int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')] for _ in range(6)]  
print(max([sum(arr[i][j:j+3])+sum(arr[i+1][j+1])+sum(arr[i+2][j:j+3]) for i, j in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=2)]))
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(max([sum(arr[i][j:j+3])+sum(arr[i+1][j+1])+sum(arr[i+2][j:j+3]) for i, j in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=2)]))
  File "solution.py", line 6, in <listcomp>
    print(max([sum(arr[i][j:j+3])+sum(arr[i+1][j+1])+sum(arr[i+2][j:j+3]) for i, j in itertools.product(range(4), repeat=2)]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Split your code to different, debuggable lines and see where the error occurs.

Comment: Thank you, the second sum function in the print statement should be removed

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(arr[i+1][j+1])
```

The above code is wrong,`arr[i+1][j+1]` is an integer,not a list,that's why you got `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`:

By the way,@deepspace made a good suggestion,we'd like to write some **pythonic** code,but it is more important to write code that is easy to debug and refactor.